# Need suggestions on how to modify regex to keep the first digit in a capture group

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

```
3&gt; General Information      34&gt; 3rd Party Software
```

From this string I need to get 2 matches with 2 groups in each of them.
Using this regex `([^\s\.\)\d\-,\&gt;](\s{0,3}[^\s]+)*)` I'm getting the following result:

```
Match 1  
Full match  6-25    'General Information'  
Group 1.    6-25    'General Information'  
Group 2.    13-25   ' Information'  
Match 2  
Full match  39-56   'rd Party Software'  
Group 1.    39-56   'rd Party Software'  
Group 2.    47-56   ' Software`
```

Here is the link to [my regex demo fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/tNfMSc/1).

However, I'm missing a number 3 in my second match. Instead of '3rd Party Software' I'm getting 'rd Party Software'. Any suggestions on how to keep that digit?

Thanks.

Comment: The 3 is not captured because `[^\s\.\)\d\-,\&gt;]` excludes `\d` (decimal digit). I don't think this regex does what you think it does. For example, if the "G" in "General" were a lowercase "g", it would be excluded because the previously referenced character set also excludes `g`. It is excluding individual characters, not a sequence of characters.

Comment: What exactly is the result you want for your matches & capture groups?

Comment: @kfed Does this work for you: `(?<=\d&gt;\s)[\w\s]+(?=\s{6}|\r*\n)`?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/76T43f/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, that what I was looking for. Just change the order of the brackets to change the capturing groups a bit ([link](https://regex101.com/r/76T43f/2)). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `[^&gt;]` you match any char but `&`, `g`, `t` and `;` as `[^...]` is a negated character class construct.

You may match the digit(s) and the `&gt;` part and then match and *capture* what you need:

```
/\d+&gt;\s*([^\s.),-]+\s{0,3}((?:\s{0,3}\S+)*))/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/76T43f/2)

**Details**

- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `&gt;` - a substring
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace chars
- `([^\s.),-]+\s{0,3}((?:\s{0,3}\S+)*))` - Group 1:

  - `[^\s.),-]+` - any char but a whitespace, `.`, `)`, `,` and `-`
  - `\s{0,3}` - 0 to 3 occurrences of whitespace chars
  - `((?:\s{0,3}\S+)*)` - Group 2 matching 0 or more consecutive occurrences of

    - `\s{0,3}` - 0 to 3 occurrences of whitespace chars
    - `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace chars.